# git list branches that are merged into all of multiple other branches

Tags: git

In git, how can I list all the branches which are merged into ALL of multiple other branches?

Unfortunately,

```
git branch --merged a --merged b
```

does not do the trick as it lists branches that are merged into `a` OR `b`, whereas I want branches merged into `a` AND `b`. This is despite the man page claiming that --merged "Only list branches whose tips are reachable from the specified commit". `git for-each-ref` has similar behavior.

I managed to get the desired behavior with

```
comm -12 \
  <(git for-each-ref --merged=a 'refs/heads/*' --format='%(refname:lstrip=2)' | sort) \
  <(git for-each-ref --merged=b 'refs/heads/*' --format='%(refname:lstrip=2)' | sort)
```

but that command line is rather long and unwieldy, and it gets even longer and more unwieldy if I want to --exclude some branches from the list, specify a more complex --format, or specify more than two 'merged-into' branches. So I would like to find a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to say "commit `x` is merged in all branches" is "commit `x` is a common ancestor to all branches".

This second property translates to "commit `x` is an ancestor to one of the least common ancestors", and you can use `git merge-base [some options]` to have git compute these.

---

You can get the list of least common ancestors with:

```
git merge-base --octopus --all [your list of refs]
```

the list of branches you are looking for is :

```
git branch --list  --merged [that list]   # <- and having the 'or' of that list is correct
```

Grouping the two commands in a small script:

```
#!/bin/bash

merged_args=$(
    # get the list of candidate 'least common ancestors'
    git merge-base --octopus --all "$@" |
    # turn each 'eacf32..' into '--merged eacf32...'
    sed -e 's/^/--merged /'
)

git branch --list $merged_args   # <- no quotes here, the intention is to split that string
                                 #    on 'spaces' and use these as individual arguments
```

if you really want to say "here's a one liner", just insert the `$( ... )` block in the second command (again: no quotes around the `"$( ... )"`, you want to generate a list of arguments).

---

*About `git merge-base` and least common ancestors:*

- the `--all` option instructs `git merge-base` to list *all* common ancestors (default is to list only one)

there are situations when there isn't a single common ancestors, for example when there are cross merges :

```
*   0c7337c (mergeleft) Merge branch 'right' into mergeleft
|\  
| | * 10024d7 (mergeright) Merge branch 'left' into mergeright
| |/| 
| |/  
|/|   
* | 75848c2 (left) commit on left branch
| * 7975c22 (right) commit on right branch
|/  
* 0c5e7e0 (master) second commit
* df51442 first commit
```

if you look for least common ancestors to `mergeleft` and `mergeright`, both `75848c2 (left)` and `7975c22 (right)` qualify, and they have no ancestry relation (`left` is not a parent of `right`, `right` is not a parent of `left`).

Additionally:
in this situation, if you want to look at the branches that are merged in `mergeleft` *and* `mergeright`, it is ok to be merged in `left` *or* `right` (<- any of the least common ancestors).

So `git branch --merged left --merged right` is the list you are looking for.

- the `--octopus` option instructs `git merge-base` to search for ancestors common to all individual branches on the command line.

the default behavior when specifying more than 2 branches (e.g: `git merge-base a b c d`) is different; it is a bit convoluted and is documented in [`git help merge-base`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#_operation_modes):

> More generally, among the two commits to compute the merge base from, one
> is specified by the first commit argument on the command line; the other
> commit is a (possibly hypothetical) commit that is a merge across all the
> remaining commits on the command line.
>
> As a consequence, the merge base is not necessarily contained in each of
> the commit arguments if more than two commits are specified.

the bottom line is: the default behavior is not the one you are looking for in your situation

Comment: about the script: if you name your script `git-someting` (for example: `git-integrated`) and place that script on your `PATH`, then you can use `git something ...` as if it were a regular git command.

Comment: This works great. And thank you for the explanation of the different components of the solution.